# Wrap every x amount of items inside a div - Php while loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, while-loop

I have some code that is working to wrap every 2 posts in a div. I am now wanting to wrap the posts in a div every 6 or maybe 8.

The code is here:

```
<?php 

            $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
                'post_type' => 'latest_posts', 
                'posts_per_page' => 100, 
                'post_status' => 'publish' ) ); ?>

                <?php $i = 0; ?>
                
            <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                <?php if ( $i % 2 ==  0) : ?>
                    <div class="flex-content-container">
                <?php endif; ?>

                <div class="latest-posts">

                        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                
                </div>

                <!-- changed == 0 to != 0  -->
                <?php if ( $i % 2 != 0 ) : ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

            <?php $i++; endwhile; 
            ?>

            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

             <!-- added closing </div> for odd number of posts -->
        <?php if ( $i % 2 != 0 ) : ?>
        </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

I thought I could just change the 2 to whatever number I wanted but that didn't seem to work.

Any help please?

Comment: change that two inside "( $i % 2 ==  0)" to 6.. or whatever you want (assuming this currently works - havent tested). however... this might be the wrong way? are you simply trying to make those grab 50% of the screen?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.

I'm trying to wrap every 6 (maybe 8) posts in a flex-content-container div

changing "( $i % 2 == 0)" to 6

gives me two posts inside the div and then 4 posts outside

Comment: ok.. let me do a check of the actuall loop with some demo data

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, i organized a bit - hope it's to your liking (each coder etc)
you can set the "divider" at the top.

```
<?php
$result     = '';
$posts      = array();
$divider    = 6;

// The Query
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'latest_posts', 
    'posts_per_page'=> 100, 
    'post_status'   => 'publish'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    
        $posts[] = '
        <div class="post">
            <div class="p-3">
                <a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        ';

    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();


$postsGrouped = array_chunk($posts, $divider);

foreach($postsGrouped as $group){
    $result .= '<div class="flex-container">'.implode('', $group).'</div>';
}
?>

<div class="latest-posts"><?php echo $result; ?></div>
```

**Explanation:**
We are running through posts, collecting them into an array and at the end we use 'array_chunk' function to group them. Then rebuild for echoing and were done.

**Control the number of items per block / wrap here:**

```
$divider    = 6;
```

**Please note:**
in this line, we are wrapping with a final div

```
echo '<div class="latest-posts">'.$result.'</div>';
```

You can control what class that div has.

Comment: Thanks for this. The outputted html is that some posts are within a flex-container div, then 5 arent etc...
`

Comment: Oops... Forgot to check if it's the last post. can you try now?

Comment: Result is a 'latest posts' div containing a 'flex-container' div (which contains 5 'posts' divs), as well as 6 'post' divs. Then a 'flex-container' div containing four 'post' divs and then a seperate 'post' div.

Comment: Its weird, i tested it on a temp domain: http://a145091-tmp.s998.upress.link/  (in my test used 'post_type' => 'post' ofcourse. ok, lets make it in a better way - a bit more PHP complex but its the way I would do it. i updated the code and the explanation.

Comment: Great, thats working thanks. How can I set the $posts variable so the html is not in ' '. I have js and php to add in it

Comment: Edited my answer... if this answer is good dont forget to mark it as correct so it would get archived and not stay pending. Glad to help ;)

Comment: Sorry, think I didn't explain properly - I'm looking for a way of trying to move the html out of the $posts[] = '  ' section, so I can add in a load more html, js and php. Maybe being able to surround the html with an open and close tag for the $posts php variable?

Comment: Hmmm.. the post var is just an array to make thing organized. Javascript u can add at the end. No need to place it in a specific location. Seperating the php from the html is not needed... load more is a different quetion (its not hard). You could place a button at the bottom  .latest_posts and make use of css and js (guess were not talking about ajax). In anycase its a different question 

Comment: I didn't mean a load more button, I just meant there is a lot more html, js and php to go in the variable (I removed it all for the sake of a simpler example to show)

Comment: Got you, there should be no JS directly inside it.. More PHP and HTML are not a problem (or the JS code). If you need to ask "how do I integrate this HTML into each run of the loop is a different question (and not a hard one my friend). Place your JS at the bottom of the page under one script tag.  Please open a different question with that different topic. I would try to help if I am first to answer..

Comment: As a very short explention... you can just place your HTML inside those wrapping single quotes. A PHP variable is wrapped inside "external" single quotes like so <strong>The post title is '.get_the_title().'</strong> - Got it? i could extend with additional information in a relevant question.